# Call java program using db trigger running on different machine

Tags: java, database, oracle11g, database-trigger, ojdbc

I have oracle database 11g running on one machine and I have created a Java application running on a different machine on the same network.

I have created a DB trigger to monitor if any row gets updated in one of the tables in DB then my java method from the running application on a remote server should get called.

I want to know how to do that calling java method from the application running on different server.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this through a database trigger and not through something else like RMI?

Comment: I don’t know if it can be done by RMI . Please tell me the process

Comment: You just want to call a method in your code from another machine, right? That's what RMI is for, "RMI (Remote Method Invocation) is an API that provides a mechanism to create distributed application in java. The RMI allows an object to invoke methods on an object running in another JVM."

Comment: sorry, I haven't provided the whole information in my question. Updated the same now can you please help me with this.